# Does the WidgetsBindingObserver work on a stateless widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use the WidgetsBindingObserver to see if my app is brought to the foreground. But it doesn't seem do anything. Does it only work on a statefull widget?

```
class TheHomeView extends StatelessWidget with WidgetsBindingObserver {

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    print('lifecycle changed');
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      print('resumed');
      showLatestGroupNotification();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it turns out, you can use it in a stateless widget. But you need to use

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
```

which you can do in the constructor of the widget. But if you want to remove the binding on dispose

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
```

You would need a dispose which is only available in a statefull widget. Or you would have to do it manually.

https://dev.to/pedromassango/onresume-and-onpause-for-widgets-on-flutter-27k2